# CouchDB CORS configuration for https

Tags: https, couchdb, cors

My CouchDB configuration for CORS is failing for https calls, but the same is working for http.
My cors config on CouchDB is as follows,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check your certificates with another server.
I personally had a problem with CouchDB and self sign certificates, if possible try with real one :)
You can try the certificates on another server first, and if it fails there as well, try with other certificates. If not ... more debug :)

Also please have in mind CORS support in browsers - http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors
Since most of them do support it, but nothing is said about https support of cors.
You can share more info of course as well, to have the whole picture :)
Good luck

Comment: No CORS with https, true.

Comment: We could secure couchdb with  Layer 7 implementation.